# How load a XML from a URL in C# console program and get content into variables

Tags: c#, .net, xml, url, console

----- **UPDATED** -----

I have a question, simple for the more experts in c# (I am a Java dissident) and I will apreciate your help to do a good thing here using the right technique and technologies.

**What I need**

Load a XML file from a URL.
After this I need navigate between the information sets getting the data and put it into some variables.

This will be a .NET C# executable program , stand alone that other program in COBOL will run and recuperate the data.

The exemple XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<movie>
  <title>
    Fast Five
  </title>
  <year>
    2011
  </year>
  <description>
    Dominic Toretto and his crew of street racers plan a massive heist ...
  </description>
  <director>
    <director_1>Justin Lin</director_1>
    <director_2>Vovó Mafalda</director_2>
  </director>
</movie>
```

Accessible in, localhost:8080\movie.xml, for example.

I have a code to load a XML:

```
namespace main
{
    public class XMLLoader
    {
        public static void getXMLContent()
        {
            String title = null;
            String year = null;
            String description = null;
            String director1 = null;
            String director2 = null;
            String director3 = null;

            try
            {
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load("http://localhost:8081/xml/movies.xml");

                title       = (xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("title")[0]).InnerText.Trim();
                year        = (xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("year")[0]).InnerText.Trim();
                description = (xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("description")[0]).InnerText.Trim();
                director1   = (xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("director_1")[0]).InnerText.Trim();
                director2   = (xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("director_2")[0]).InnerText.Trim();
                director3   = (xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("director_3")[0]).InnerText.Trim();

                Console.WriteLine("Movie......: " + title);
                Console.WriteLine("Year.......: " + year);
                Console.WriteLine("Description: " + description);
                Console.WriteLine("Director1..: " + director1);
                Console.WriteLine("Director2..: " + director2);
                Console.WriteLine("Director3..: " + director3);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("        Error to load URL");
                Console.WriteLine("        Message: " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            getXMLContent();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

But this smells bad for me.

There is a more efficient and beautiful way to do it?
And how to load a XML from a URL in a console C# program?

Thanks for all help and attention.

Comment: The fact that you're in a console application doesn't matter. It will be handled the same way no matter where you're processing the document. It's a rather trivial point, but something I just wanted to make sure you understand as you're new to .NET. Other than that, take a look at the `XDocument` object, and do some research on LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 1):

[XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can read from a URI:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("http://localhost:8080/movie.xml");
var movie = doc.SelectSingleNode("/movies/movie");
```

There are a few different ways of reading XML from C#. For simple, small structures (and especially remote ones), I find `XmlDocument` to be the shortest method.

Comment: Hi RGraham. I'll search how to read the document with XmlDocument. Some tip? Thanks for help me.

Comment: I would read this tutorial on XPath. Should held a lot: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recent version of the .NET Framework (3.5 or later I think) you can use the `XDocument` class which has Load and Parse methods on it. Once you have your `XDocument` class you can use Linq to XML to build an anonymous type to hold your data, something like:-

```
const string xmlData = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><movie><title>Fast Five</title><year>2011</year><description>Dominic Toretto and his crew of street racers plan a massive heist to buy their freedom while in the sights of a powerful Brazilian drug lord and a dangerous federal agent.</description><director>Justin Lin</director></movie>";

var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);
var movie = from docRoot in xdoc.Descendants("movie")
            let titleElement = docRoot.Element("title") where titleElement != null
            let yearElement = docRoot.Element("year") where yearElement != null
            let descriptionElement = docRoot.Element("description") where descriptionElement != null
            select new
            {
                Title = titleElement.Value,
                Year = yearElement.Value,
                Description = descriptionElement.Value
            };
```

Comment: Kane, thanks for this tip. But when I try it is generated the error: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'.  'Select' not found.  Are you missing a reference to 'System.Core.dll' or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?

Comment: But the References in the project is ok (System.Core and System.Xml.Linq is there!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinQ to XML to get the data from an XML structure. Here's [**an article**](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=564) on this. Basically if this is your XML:

```
<movies>
  <movie>
    <title>
      Fast Five
    </title>
    <year>
      2011
    </year>
    <description>
      Dominic Toretto and his crew of street racers plan a massive heist to buy their freedom while in the sights of a powerful Brazilian drug lord and a dangerous federal agent.
    </description>
    <director>
      Justin Lin
    </director>
  </movie>
<movies>
```

Your code looks like this:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("PATH_TO_XML");
IEnumerable<XElement> movies = xelement.Elements();

foreach (var movie in movies)
{
    var title = employee.Element("title").Value);
    //and so on...
}
```